# C#: No way to change FlatAppearance Settings on buttons when using Control.Add(new Button())

Tags: c#, winforms, button, formatting

I'm currently trying to change FlatAppearance.BorderSize, when creating a button via Control.Add(new Button()) method but when using:

```
Controls.Add (new Button(FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0,))
```

it just returns an error saying that FlatAppearance does not exist. The buttons are created one after another listing information about songs. Each Section is created button by button in a FlowLayoutPanel. Is there any work around for removing the border on the button?

```
selectTrackNo.Connection = DB.connect;
        MySqlDataReader trackNoReader = selectTrackNo.ExecuteReader();
        while (trackNoReader.Read())
        {
            flpTrackNo.Controls.Add(new Button
            {
                Name = "lblTrackNo" + x,
                Text = trackNoReader[0] as string,
                BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                AutoSize = false,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                Width = flpArtist.Width,
                ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3c3c3c"),
                Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 9),
                Enabled = true,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
            });
            x++;
        }
```

this then repeats for every column in the Form.
Many thanks
 - Ross

Comment: If you want view all of the source code you can download it from: https://github.com/Rossosaurus/KEVINMusicPlayer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a couple more squiggly brackets:

```
this.Controls.Add(new Button() { FlatAppearance = { BorderSize = 0 }});
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thanks a bunch

Comment: @RossUnderhill When a post answers your question you can mark it as accepted answer by click on check-mark near the post. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @RossUnderhill By the way, additional to using object initializer syntax, you can simply create a variable of type `Button`, set its properties and then add it to `Controls` collection of form.